# Is it ok to have JSON objects with varying number of attributes?

Tags: json, api, rest

I am designing an API resonse for my mobile app right now, and response should contain array of operations. Some of them might have all attributes, some may not, see the example:

```
{
"operations":[
        {
            "type":"0",
            "location":"01"
        },
        {
            "type":"1",
            "location":"1234"
            "item_id":"",
            "item_name":"Item A",
        }
    ]
}
```

Is that a good way, or should I reconsider my design? I mean the varying number of attribues. Thank you!

Comment: keep null or empty string for attributes that dont have values..

Comment: There's no standard to tell you what's allowed and not, but I'm siding with zzlalani. Providing the attributes with values indicated they're not set or not valid for this object will make it much easier using your API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although It will be good for the bandwidth to keep the attributes out of the json string that doesn't have values. But I will suggest you to keep it other way, either send `null` or empty string `""` it will be help at the decoding side

```
{
"operations":[
        {
            "type":"0",
            "location":"01"
            "item_id":null,
            "item_name":null,
        },
        {
            "type":"1",
            "location":"1234"
            "item_id":"",
            "item_name":"Item A",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the code you'll be writing to handle the object :) As long as you write your code to handle missing elements you'll be fine.

Javascript couldn't give a hoot if an object in an array matches the structure of the other objects or not, if that's what you're concerned about.

p.s: Watch those comma's! They cause me more grief than anything else :p IE will break on a trailing comma :(